# Django loading json objects to templates

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting data from firebase

views.py

```
def posts (request):
     _posts= ref.child('posts').get();  #getting data from firebase
     #_posts={u'1536855154789': 
     #      {u'content': u'Yahoo! The sports day is near!!', 
     #       u'image': u'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/.../img_1536855147507.jpeg?', 
     #       u'title': u'Sports Day'}, 
     #u'-LMJBAc3iZRklICAwDC1': 
     #     {u'content': u'Find the chef in your child. Food fest is here!!', 
     #      u'image': u'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/.../img_1536863277649.jpeg?', 
     #      u'title': u'Food Fest '}, 
     #u'-LNaLKKqSIZHraf3oedT': 
     #     {u'content': u'Exploring is part of education. Hence a tour to Historical and Cultural Heritage monuments in Delhi has been planned.',
     #      u'image': u'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/.../img_1538241669221.jpeg', 
     #      u'title': u'Educational Tour'}}
     return render(request, 'post.html', {'postList': _posts})
```

index.html

```
 {% for item in postList %}
 {{ item.title}}</br>
 {% endfor %}
```

Its returning nothing

my firebase data
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxYsC.png

Help me solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: That screenshot is not helpful. Show the contents of `_posts`, as (properly formatted) text.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work if you had a list of dicts. But you don't; you have a single dictionary, whose keys are the IDs and the values are themselves dicts. So you need to iterate over the dict values:

```
 {% for item in postList.values %}
 {{ item.title}}</br>
 {% endfor %}
```